# Using Flint Particles with AIR. Kindle Fire (20fps) vs. iPad 2 (6fps)

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, mobile, air, particle-system

This refers to Flint Particle System for AS3.

I'm using AIR3.5 for mobile development, so I took the Pachinko example (http://flintparticles.org/examples/pachinko) and tried it on several devices. Surprisingly, it's much faster on 1st generation Kindle Fire (20fps) than on iPad 2 (only 6fps). This is the first time I see iPad 2 loosing to Kindle Fire, let alone by such a large margin.

Any idea why is this happening and are there any pitfalls in using Flint for mobile development in general? Any advice on other viable options would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: What parameters did you use when publishing for iOS?

Comment: Same as always. Render Mode: direct, Full Screen, Resolution: High.

Comment: Have you tried using a tool such as Monocle to profile the application? As far as I know Flint uses display list rendering (as opposed to Stage3D) which might be pretty slow on older device such as iPad 1/2. I don't know the specs of the Kindle, is it supposed to be more powerful than an iPad 2? That would explain the difference.

Comment: I have not tried Monocle. I figure if there's a bottleneck in Flint, I'm not going to rewrite it anyway. I've been testing my apps on Kindle and iPad 2 for about a year and the iPad has been **consistently** faster by about 30-50%, which makes sense. Why it so much slower in this particular case is a big mystery. I just couldn't beleive it when I saw it. BTW, same code runs at 4fps on iPod Touch 4.